# Magento error, suddenly meet “Cannot apply the coupon code.”

Tags: php, magento

I'm getting an `Cannot apply the coupon code.` error. And here is the exception from the `exception.log` file:

```
2014-10-25T05:16:24+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Exception' with message 'Item (Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule) with the same id "8" already exist' in /home/fduggcom/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php:373
Stack trace: enter code here#0 /home/fduggcom/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(576):
Varien_Data_Collection->addItem(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))#1/home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php(100):
Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()#2 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote/Freeshipping.php(60):
Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator->init('1', '0', 'WECHAT5%OFF')#3 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php(957):
Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))#4 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1263):
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()#5 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/Model/Sales/Quote.php(27):
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()#6 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(526):
Idev_OneStepCheckout_Model_Sales_Quote->collectTotals()#7 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
Mage_Checkout_CartController->couponPostAction()#8 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('couponPost')#9 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))#10 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))#11 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()#12 /home/fduggcom/public_html/app/Mage.php(683):
Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)#13 /home/fduggcom/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')#14 {main}
```

Can someone please give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace you give 'Item (Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule) with the same id "8" already exist'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What does this message mean? id "8" is the product or discount rule?

Comment: Same id on discount rule. What scenario did you get this error?

Comment: I have checked the id of all discount rules, which are different. I got this error when I try to use a coupon code on shopping cart page. the error message 'Cannot apply the coupon code' showed. And the problem happen without I changed any setting or module. It is really strange.

Comment: Did you already try clearing and refreshing the magento cache or tried reindexing the products?

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work. But I solved this problem by delete the code of the error. However I still don't know why the error happens, but it works properly now.